# JS Canvas get pixel value very frequently

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, pixi.js

I am creating a video game based on Node.js/WebGL/Canvas/PIXI.js.

In this game, blocks have a generic size: they can be circles, polygons, or everything. So, my physical engine needs to know where exactly the things are, what pixels are walls and what pixels are not. Since I think PIXI don't allow this, I create an invisible canvas where I put all the wall's images of the map. Then, I use the function getImageData to create a function "isWall" at (x, y):

```
function isWall(x, y):
    return canvas.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3] != 0;
```

However, this is very slow (it takes up to 70% of the CPU time of the game, according to Chrome profiling). Also, since I introduced this function, I sometimes got the error "Oops, WebGL crashed" without any additional advice.

Is there a better method to access the value of the pixel? I thought about storing everything in a static bit array (walls have a fixed size), with 1 corresponding to a wall and 0 to a non-wall. Is it reasonable to have a 10-million-cells array in memory?

Comment: Doing collisions on pixels is pretty much an anti-pattern now-a-days. In order to read pixels on modern GPU the entire GPU pipeline has to be stalled (like slamming the brakes on a car) so the CPU can then read the pixels. The GPU then zooms away to do more stuff. Imagine a race car that had to slam on the breaks and come to a complete stop every time you wanted to look at it. That's what reading pixels does a modern GPU.
The point being, is there some other way you can do the collisions? Polygons? AABB? Primitives? Or, render your own collision pixels on CPU?

Comment: The second idea doesn't require to call the GPU, as walls are static and can be stored in an array that has nothing to do with the GPU. It's interesting however that you are saying that this is nowadays an anti-pattern. But how people do when they want to do pixel-wise collision? My game will have a lot of complex forms, and I don't want to manually create a polygon that looks like the form for each of them, because it would take me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use bit arrays to store **0 || 1** info and it works very well.

The information is stored compactly and gets/sets are very fast.

Here is the bit library I use:

https://github.com/drslump/Bits-js/blob/master/lib/Bits.js

I've not tried with 10m bits so you'll have to try it on your own dataset.

The solution you propose is very "flat", meaning each pixel must have a corresponding bit. This results in a large amount of memory being required--even if information is stored as bits.

**An alternative testing data ranges instead of testing each pixel:**

If the number of wall pixels is small versus the total number of pixels you might try storing each wall as a series of "runs". For example, a wall run might be stored in an object like this (warning: untested code!):

```
// an object containing all horizontal wall runs
var xRuns={}

// an object containing all vertical wall runs
var yRuns={}

// define a wall that runs on y=50 from x=100 to x=185
// and then runs on x=185 from y=50 to y=225
var y=50;
var x=185;

if(!xRuns[y]){ xRuns[y]=[]; }

xRuns[y].push({start:100,end:185});

if(!yRuns[x]){ yRuns[x]=[]; }

yRuns[x].push({start:50,end:225});
```

Then you can quickly test an [x,y] against the  wall runs like this (warning untested code!):

```
function isWall(x,y){

    if(xRuns[y]){
        var a=xRuns[y];
        var i=a.length;
        do while(i--){
            var run=a[i];
            if(x>=run.start && x<=run.end){return(true);}
        }
    }

    if(yRuns[x]){
        var a=yRuns[x];
        var i=a.length;
        do while(i--){
            var run=a[i];
            if(y>=run.start && y<=run.end){return(true);}
        }
    }

    return(false);

}
```

This should require very few tests because the x & y exactly specify which array of xRuns and yRuns need to be tested.

It may (or may not) be faster than testing the "flat" model because there is overhead getting to the specified element of the flat model. You'd have to perf test using both methods.

The wall-run method would likely require much less memory.

Hope this helps...Keep in mind the wall-run alternative is just off the top of my head and probably requires tweaking ;-)

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting and I may be using that in the future. I am still looking for other answers to know if this is the right solution (someone else disagree).

Comment: Fair enough! As I mention in my post, you will have to try the approaches in order to determine which one maximizes performance in your most desirable way. Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- For first check: Use collision regions for all of your objects. The regions can even be defined for each side depending on shape (ie. complex shapes). Only check for collisions inside intersecting regions.
- Use half resolution for hit-test bitmaps (or even 25% if your scenario allow). Our brains are not capable of detecting pixel-accurate collisions when things are moving so this can be taken advantage of.
- For complex shapes, *pre*-store the *whole* bitmap for it (based on its region(s)) but transform it to a single value typed array like Uint8Array with high and low values (re-use this instead of getting one and one pixels via the context). Subtract object's position and use the result as a delta for your shape region, then hit-testing the "bitmap". If the shape rotates, transform incoming check points accordingly (there is probably a sweet-spot here where updating bitmap becomes faster than transforming a bunch of points etc. You need to test for your scenario).
- For close-to-square shaped objects do a compromise and use a simple rectangle check
- For circles and ellipses use un-squared values to check distances for radius.
- In some cases you can perhaps use *collision predictions* which you calculate before the games starts and when knowing all objects positions, directions and velocities (calculate the complete motion path, find intersections for those paths, calculate time/distance to those intersections). If your objects change direction etc. due to other events during their path, this will of course not work so well (or try and see if re-calculating is beneficial or not).

I'm sure why you would need 10m stored in memory, it's doable though - but you will need to use something like a quad-tree and split the array up, so it becomes efficient to look up a pixel state. IMO you will only need to store "bits" for the complex shapes, and you can limit it further by defining multiple regions per shape. For simpler shapes just use vectors (rectangles, radius/distance). Do performance tests often to find the right balance.

In any case - these sort of things has to be hand-optimized for the very scenario, so this is just a general take on it. Other factors will affect the approach such as high velocities, rotation, reflection etc. and it will quickly become very broad. Hope this gives some input though.

Comment: Upvote for useful thoughts on collisions! You mention collision predictions...Last Christmas I did some work on reducing total required collision tests by determining the minimum number of move-cycles objectA would need to possibly collide with objectB. It turned out to be (surprisingly!) efficient with large numbers of projectiles that need to be collision tested against each other.